# Is there any mechanism to generate an "ownership tree" visualization with Rust or the Rust tooling?

Tags: rust, ownership

In Chapter 4 of [*"Programming Rust"* by Jim Blandy & Jason Orendorff](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust/9781491927274/ch04.html) it says,

> It follows that the owners and their owned values form trees: your owner is your parent, and the values you own are your children. And at the ultimate root of each tree is a variable; when that variable goes out of scope, the entire tree goes with it. **We can see such an ownership tree in the diagram for composers**: it’s not a “tree” in the sense of a search tree data structure, or an HTML document made from DOM elements. Rather, we have a tree built from a mixture of types, with Rust’s single-owner rule forbidding any rejoining of structure that could make the arrangement more complex than a tree. Every value in a Rust program is a member of some tree, rooted in some variable.

An example is provided,

[image: Rust Ownership Tree]

This is simplified and pretty, but is there any mechanism to generate an "ownership tree" visualization with Rust or the Rust tooling? Can I dump an ownership tree when debugging?

Comment: No, there is not.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a specific tool for it, but you can get pretty close by deriving the `Debug` trait. When you derive the `Debug` trait for a struct, it will give you a recursive representation of all owned data, terminating at primitive types such as `str`, `u32` etc, or when it encounters a custom `Debug` implementation.
For example, this program here:

```rust
use rand;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum State {
    Good,
    Bad,
    Ugly(&'static str),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ExampleStruct {
    x_factor: Option<f32>,
    children: Vec<ExampleStruct>,
    state: State,
}

impl ExampleStruct {
    fn random(max_depth: usize) -> Self {
        use rand::Rng;
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

        let child_count = match max_depth {
            0 => 0,
            _ => rng.gen::<usize>() % max_depth,
        };

        let mut children = Vec::with_capacity(child_count);

        for _ in 0..child_count {
            children.push(ExampleStruct::random(max_depth - 1));
        }

        let state = if rng.gen() {
            State::Good
        } else if rng.gen() {
            State::Bad
        } else {
            State::Ugly("really ugly")
        };

        Self {
            x_factor: Some(rng.gen()),
            children,
            state,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = ExampleStruct::random(3);
    dbg!(foo);
}
```

prints something like this:

```
[src/main.rs:51] foo = ExampleStruct {
    x_factor: Some(
        0.27388978,
    ),
    children: [
        ExampleStruct {
            x_factor: Some(
                0.5051847,
            ),
            children: [
                ExampleStruct {
                    x_factor: Some(
                        0.9675246,
                    ),
                    children: [],
                    state: Ugly(
                        "really ugly",
                    ),
                },
            ],
            state: Bad,
        },
        ExampleStruct {
            x_factor: Some(
                0.70672345,
            ),
            children: [],
            state: Ugly(
                "really ugly",
            ),
        },
    ],
    state: Bad,
}
```

Note that not all the data is in line: The children live somewhere else on the heap. They are not stored inside the ExampleStruct, they are simply owned by it.

This could get confusing if you store references to things, because Debug may start to traverse these references. It does not matter to Debug that they aren't owned. In fact, this is the case with the `&'static str` inside `State::Ugly`. The actual bytes that make up the string are not owned by any variable, they are hard coded and live inside the program itself. They will exist for as long as the program is running.